# Overriding default behaviour of anchor tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I am trying to override the default behaviour of an anchor tag so i can load in a web page on my server into the exisiting div, rather than a new tab or window.

so far i have:

```
myContainer.click(function(){                   
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('a').click(function(){
                        var link = $(this).attr('href');
                        myContainer.load(link);
                    });
            });
```

In chrome i have to click the link twice before it does anything, in IE an FF it doesnt work at all and refreshes the page with the new link.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Shouldn't it be just:

```
 $('a').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
     myContainer.load(this.href);
 });
```

Your code assigns a click handler inside a click handler. So the *first* click will attach the click handler to the link, and the *second* click (on the link) will execute the new click handler.

It seems you only need **one** click handler. If the links are added dynamically, you can use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) (the successor of [`.live`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`.delegate`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)):

```
myContainer.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
     myContainer.load(this.href);
});

// or

$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
     myContainer.load(this.href);
});
```

Comment: you absolute beauty! works perfectly man! btw whats the difference between live and delegate?

Comment: @Julio: `live` adds an event handler to the document root (so the event has to bubble up the whole DOM tree) whereas `delegate` adds the event handler to a certain element (`myContainer` in this case). So in this `delegate` example, only click events on links *inside* `myContainer` are handled, whereas the with, a click on every link will be handled (although you could also write `$('#myContainer a').live()`. But as I said, with `delegate`, the event handler can be bound to an element closer to originating elements. You should prefer `delegate` over `live`.

Comment: Thanks man! Awesome information. Also for missing the missing the event - schoolboy error!I'm in the process of writing a custom tab plugin for a specific in browser app so this is really useful information. Basically open certain links in new tabs or exsiting tabs, managing the tabs, browser history etc - any tips advice in the realm of this problem?

Comment: @Julio: There is no general advice I can give.... just try and search on SO for things like handling browser history the best way.

Comment: @FelixKling That is very good advice. I've often seen developers use .live because "it always works" and they are usually clueless about what's happening under the hood.  .live(), .bind(), .delegate() all use .on() internally since jQuery 1.7.  It's good they deprecated .live(), it was becoming bad practice for many new devs.

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to pass in event:

```
myContainer.click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
 $('a').click(function(){ var link = $(this).attr('href');
 myContainer.load(link);
 });
 });
```

try to rearrange them:

```
myContainer.ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
     myContainer.load(link);
     });
     });
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, its fixed the IE and FF problem but still have to click link twice before anything happens